# Show wordpress widget in particular area of a page content area

Tags: wordpress, widget

Can anybody suggest me how can I add a wordpress widget to a particular area of mu custom page template?

For example I have a file called blog-template.php and in that file I have a div.

I want to show a widget in that div, not sidebars neither footer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes 
See, Create New Widget Area Using Custom Function

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follow.

Add your widget function to `functions.php`

```
class My_Custom_Widget extends WP_Widget 
{ 
/* your code* / 
}
```

Call the widget from `blog-template.php.`

```
<?php the_widget( 'My_Custom_Widget' ); ?>
```